# Change route using browser back button in angular 6

Tags: angular6, back-button

I have an website in angular6 and I want to change URL on click of browser back button using `onPopState` but its not working. TS file of desired route component load but failing to stay and gets redirected as per browser history.

I am using below code

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private _phonenumberService: PhonenumberService, 
    private router: Router, 
    private apiService: ApiServiceService, 
    public location: Location, 
    public plocation: LocationStrategy) {
            this.plocation.onPopState(() => {
              console.log('Back button pressed');
              this.router.navigate(['/home'],  {replaceUrl:true});
          });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one. Import HostListener

`import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';`

And then bind event

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onBrowserBackBtnClose(event: Event) {
    console.log('back button pressed');
    event.preventDefault(); 
    this.router.navigate(['/home'],  {replaceUrl:true});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I did this same way and it worked. :)